# Can a stream be created from an object that has only exposed the "readNext" portion of an iterator?

Tags: java, java-8

I trying to read from a csv file, but due to its size, without loading it all into memory first.

The library I found for reading csv is `opencsv`, which works really well, but only exposes two methods:

```
readAll()
```

and

```
readNext()
```

`readAll` is out, as I don't want it all in memory at the same time, so I'd like to use lazily read from the file via `readNext`. And ideally, i'd like to wrap up that reading via a stream.

The closest I've gotten was giving the `readnext` method to a `Stream.generate` construct,

```
Stream csvDataStream = Stream.generate(csvReader::readNext);
```

but this obviously has the massive draw back of throwing an error once the iterator underlying `csvReader` is exhausted. I don't really want to wrap my entire program in a try/catch block because I'm using the language wrong. Is there a way to create a stream from something that only exposes a `next` method?

Comment: @HotLicks opencsv's cursor-based API is a cosy fit for the Streams API.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Implement a `Spliterator`.  You need only implement the `tryAdvance` method with a nontrivial implementation; `trySplit` can return `null`, `characteristics()` can return ORDERED, and `estimateSize` can return Long.MAX_VALUE.  Then call `StreamSupport.stream(Spliterator)` to make a stream.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a ready-made implementation from my project. I have an abstract spliterator which handles splitting into fixed-size batches and allows for efficient parallelization of processing of any kind of I/O-based stream source:

```
import static java.util.Spliterators.spliterator;

import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Spliterator;
import java.util.function.Consumer;

public abstract class FixedBatchSpliteratorBase<T> implements Spliterator<T> {
  private final int batchSize;
  private final int characteristics;
  private long est;

  public FixedBatchSpliteratorBase(int characteristics, int batchSize, long est) {
    characteristics |= ORDERED;
    if ((characteristics & SIZED) != 0) characteristics |= SUBSIZED;
    this.characteristics = characteristics;
    this.batchSize = batchSize;
    this.est = est;
  }
  public FixedBatchSpliteratorBase(int characteristics, int batchSize) {
    this(characteristics, batchSize, Long.MAX_VALUE);
  }
  public FixedBatchSpliteratorBase(int characteristics) {
    this(characteristics, 64, Long.MAX_VALUE);
  }

  @Override public Spliterator<T> trySplit() {
    final HoldingConsumer<T> holder = new HoldingConsumer<>();
    if (!tryAdvance(holder)) return null;
    final Object[] a = new Object[batchSize];
    int j = 0;
    do a[j] = holder.value; while (++j < batchSize && tryAdvance(holder));
    if (est != Long.MAX_VALUE) est -= j;
    return spliterator(a, 0, j, characteristics());
  }
  @Override public Comparator<? super T> getComparator() {
    if (hasCharacteristics(SORTED)) return null;
    throw new IllegalStateException();
  }
  @Override public long estimateSize() { return est; }
  @Override public int characteristics() { return characteristics; }

  static final class HoldingConsumer<T> implements Consumer<T> {
    Object value;
    @Override public void accept(T value) { this.value = value; }
  }
}
```

And here's the opencsv spliterator based on it:

```
public class CsvSpliterator extends FixedBatchSpliteratorBase<String[]> {
  private final CSVReader cr;

  CsvSpliterator(CSVReader cr, int batchSize) {
    super(NONNULL, batchSize);
    if (cr == null) throw new NullPointerException("CSVReader is null");
    this.cr = cr;
  }
  public CsvSpliterator(CSVReader cr) { this(cr, 100); }

  @Override public void forEachRemaining(Consumer<? super String[]> action) {
    if (action == null) throw new NullPointerException();
    uncheckRun(() -> { for (String[] row; (row = cr.readNext()) != null;) action.accept(row); });
  }
  @Override public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super String[]> action) {
    if (action == null) throw new NullPointerException();
    return uncheckCall(() -> {
      final String[] row = cr.readNext();
      if (row == null) return false;
      action.accept(row);
      return true;
    });
  }
}
```

where `uncheckRun` and `uncheckCall` are

```
public static <T> T uncheckCall(Callable<T> callable) {
  try { return callable.call(); }
  catch (Exception e) { return sneakyThrow(e); }
}
public static void uncheckRun(RunnableExc r) {
  try { r.run(); } catch (Exception e) { sneakyThrow(e); }
}
public static <T> T sneakyThrow(Throwable e) {
  return Util.<RuntimeException, T>sneakyThrow0(e);
}
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private static <E extends Throwable, T> T sneakyThrow0(Throwable t) throws E { throw (E)t; }
```

Usage:

```
import static java.util.stream.StreamSupport.stream;

....

final CSVReader cr = new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(yourInputStream), separator, '"');
return stream(new CsvSpliterator(cr), true).onClose(() -> uncheckRun(cr::close));
```