# Split a spliterator into N spliterators

Tags: java, java-8

While analyzing a colleague's Java 7 code from a few years ago, I found that he implemented a utility for traversing data, potentially in parallel. He called it `Range`, and it extended the `Iterator` interface. Some of its new methods were awkwardly familiar:

- `int size()` would give the exact size of the range;
- `Range split()` would separate the range into 2 pieces, preferably, although not necessarily, similar in size (modifying the current range and creating a new one);
- `Range[] split(int n)` would separate the range into N sub-ranges, potentially attempting to make them as even as possible.
- Although `void remove()` was there from `Iterator`, its subtypes were merely throwing `UnsupportedOperationException`.

What I said to myself was that this is definitely what we can now do with (subsized) spliterators, thus taking advantage of the stream API. However, the spliterator in Java 8 does not provide an easy approach to splitting into `n` parts.

With a recursive function, we can split it up to `n = 2^L` parts with `L` recursion levels, but the approach is not as trivial when `n` is not a power of two, not to mention that it feels unnatural to keep a utility function just for the effect.

One might also say to simply avoid messing around with spliterators and let a stream do the splitting induced by forks during the actual processing, but the ForkJoin strategy might not be very adequate for the task, and does not guarantee that it will use the number of threads that we specifically wish to dedicate to the job. There could be cases of heavy tasks being performed on a small number of elements, in fact.

The question sums up to the following: having a spliterator with at least the characteristics SIZED and SUBSIZED, how can I split it into an exact number of spliterators?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to do it, which is not even that hacky and interoperates with the existing F/J support framework, is coding a spliterator *wrapper* which uses its own splitting policy. What you lose is the ability to leverage a natively random-access structure; you can only split by iterating over the inner splitetator's data set.

You can refer to my [earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24459776/1103872) where I present the code which splits into batches of predetermined size; it is quite easy to adapt it to your case with just an appropriate constructor call.

Comment: Oddly enough, I placed the question not that long after I read your blog post. Although it brings me closer to a solution, it still focuses on fixing the size of batches rather than the number of processing cores. Nonetheless, I will give your advice a go now and report back once I have some results.

Comment: That was my angle on it, but I think the same approach is very easy to adapt to the core count-driven splitting policy. In my opinion, your true problem will be the sequential nature of this approach. A SIZED spliterator is most likely to be backed by an array and an implementation leveraging that fact would be *significantly* better (O(1) splitting instead of O(n), both in space and time).

Comment: You are right! In fact, our current implementations are either backed by an  `ArrayList` or a Lucene `IndexReader`. Knowing these details in advance will surely improve performance, but it would be nice to have a generic solution here as well.

Comment: I have personal experience with `IndexReader`-backed parallelization (that's in fact exactly why I wrote those classes). Since Lucene operations are heavyweight stuff (100 µs for a lookup is not unusual), it pays off to parallelize even in the sequential mode. Note that in that case it really isn't that important to exactly match the core count with your number of batches. Give each batch enough work to do (like 10 ms) and the coordination/switching overhead vanishes.

Answer (score 2):

> “… but the ForkJoin strategy might not be very adequate for the task”

sounds like premature optimization to me. You want to implement complicated things manually because the existing strategy *might* be inadequate…

> “… and does not guarantee that it will use the number of threads that we specifically wish to dedicate to the job.”

There is no guaranty indeed, but the current stream implementation uses the [common Fork/Join pool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html#commonPool--) which [can be configured to a desired number of threads](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28694434/2711488). Dedicating a specified number of threads to the task(s) is exactly the strategy you are asking for.

> “There could be cases of heavy tasks being performed on a small number of elements, in fact.”

I don’t see any contradiction to how the F/J framework works. It will attempt to split until the desired parallelism has been reached. If that implies that each thread is working on a single item only, well, it will do.

At this point, it’s worth noting that the default parallelism, matching the number of cores, is sufficient for any computational task that does not involve blocking, regardless of how much time processing a single item takes. As long as every thread has its workload, there is no acceleration possible beyond the number of actual hardware execution units.

In other words, the F/J frameworks implements the strategy you want to implement yourself (or a strategy which is superior to what you would implement), which brings us back to the first point, premature optimization.

Comment: You have stated some good points. But considering another use case, what if my `N` is smaller than the number of threads in the pool? AFAIK, I am unable to define a thread limit per task. The one trick I've seen around it is collecting the stream and pass it to a new ForkJoinPool.

Comment: If you have less tasks than threads you have to split the tasks itself to gain more parallelism, a thing that no one can do for you as you are the only one who knows the actual tasks and how to split them, if possible at all. I don’t see how collecting the items and passing to another pool ought to help you there, that might create a funky looking number of thread instances in your monitoring tool but for no benefit regarding parallelism as the threads of the second pool all have to wait for the completion of the collection performed by the first pool so they are not running at the same time.

Comment: Consider a target parallelism of 3. By applying the hardwired split-down-the-middle policy, ForkJoin will not be able to make an optimal, balanced split. Doesn't that give at least enough justification for an attempt at OP's approach?

Comment: @Marko Topolnik: your assumption that splitting into exactly 3 equally sized pieces will yield a perfectly balanced parallelism of 3 relies on having a constant workload being the same for every item as well as a perfect scheduler assigning each thread the same CPU time without ever being interfered by other threads/applications during the entire operation. In practice, that never holds. So the F/J strategy of creating *n* worker threads and splitting whenever a worker has nothing to do adapts much better to the reality and handles unbalanced splits at the same time.

Comment: Still, I would posit that splitting into multiples of 3 would stand a much better chance than starting out with an unbalanced split. My understanding is that F/J doesn't dynamically split whenever the workers have nothing to do; it statically *oversplits* by a factor of four. That allows idle workers to steal work from others' queues, but no further splitting occurs.

Comment: *If* the spliterator splits perfectly in the middle, there is a simple strategy to serve three workers. Just divide into four pieces and apply recursively to the first of these chunks. While processing the first tiny chunks concurrently, enough information can be gathered to find out whether the follow-up bigger chunks should be subdivided as well or not. Btw., my answer wasn’t addressed to you; your solution targets random access sources but the question was about `Spliterator` for which the OP wanted to implement a different strategy and I was saying that *that* won’t be better than F/J.

Comment: Actually, it’s not F/J doing anything, it’s the *stream* implementation which defines the strategy and the strategy will be different, depending on the stream ops and the *terminal operation*, e.g. `findFirst` will do a prefix-biased split, instead of balanced, etc.

Comment: Yes, I misspoke, I was referring to `ForEachTask` and `AbstractTask`, these are in the Streams implementation.  The splitting policy they use is based on the target size of the split. The target size is set to four times less than the full size divided by level of parallelism. Splitting for three workers as (1/4, 1/4, 1/2) must be less optimal than (1/3, 1/3, 1/3)---that's what I'm getting at.

Comment: `While processing the first tiny chunks concurrently, enough information can be gathered to find out whether the follow-up bigger chunks should be subdivided as well or not.`---maybe in a future release they'll take advantage of that. I actually asked on `lambda-dev` precisely about such a policy with respect to the inefficient policy used in `AbstractSpliterator`. But, as you pointed out, timing of one chunk is not a reliable predictor for the timing of other chunks.

Comment: Well, maybe you are better off with a custom implementation, esp. for random access sources and when your target parallelism is indeed a prime number, however, that’s always compared to a moving target. I’m not happy either with an API forcing `O(log(n))` complexity just for the splitting, but I have my doubts about the usefulness of custom implementations. There’s a lot a developer can do wrong…